# DHCP can not obtain correct IP sometimes

Tags: networking, dhcp

I installed Ubuntu lucid on my Thinkpad x201i laptop.Recently I found it that when I connect my cable to my laptop in our school's library,my DHCP client can not obtain correct IP. I have to set it manually to :

```
Address: 192.168.0.223
Netmask: 255.255.0.0
Gateway: 192.168.20.1
DNS Server: 202.119.32.6
```

When I run `sudo dhclient eth0`, I got the following infomation:

```
Internet Systems Consortium DHCP Client V3.1.3
Copyright 2004-2009 Internet Systems Consortium.
All rights reserved.
For info, please visit https://www.isc.org/software/dhcp/

Listening on LPF/eth0/**:**:**:**:**:**
Sending on   LPF/eth0/**:**:**:**:**:**
Sending on   Socket/fallback
DHCPDISCOVER on eth0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 3
DHCPOFFER of 192.168.0.223 from 192.168.20.6
DHCPREQUEST of 192.168.0.223 on eth0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67
DHCPACK of 192.168.0.223 from 192.168.20.6

no expiry time on offered lease.

DHCPDISCOVER on eth0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 6
DHCPOFFER of 192.168.0.223 from 192.168.20.6
DHCPREQUEST of 192.168.0.223 on eth0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67
DHCPACK of 192.168.0.223 from 192.168.20.6

no expiry time on offered lease.
```

**... The endless loop ...**

I have to type <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> to stop it.

Anybody can help me?

Comment: "I have to set it manually to :" If you want an address by DHCP, there is no need to set it manually. Where and how did you do that?

Comment: Sorry for late.I have to set it manually because DHCP can not obtain the correct IP